# How to animate Jquery objects separately

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a jQuery animation that turns a flashcard. This is the HTML:

```
<div class="stage">
<div class="flashcard">
  <div class="front">
    <p>Front</p>
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    <p>Back</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
 .stage {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;                
}

.flashcard {
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 10% auto;                                             
    border: 1px solid gray;                          
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;                                
    transition: all 0.3s;                               
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
}

.flipped, .back {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);                     
}

.front, .back {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;           
    height: 300px;                                  
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}

.front p, .back p {
    margin-top: 25%;
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

And this is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.flashcard').on('click', function() {
$('.flashcard').toggleClass('flipped');
});
});
```

I made a For loop with PHP to loop my HTML code, so it can show multiple flashcards at once. The problem is that if I click on a random flashcard, all the flashcards turn at once.

What do I have to change in my code to make sure only the clicked flashcard turns around?

Comment: Try using `$(this)` not `$(".flashcard")` on the `toggleClass()` function. Because on your script, you are literally toggling all the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$(this)` not `$(".flashcard")` on the `toggleClass()` function. Because on your script, you are literally toggling all the class. Use that to fire event on a specific element that you want to trigger.

Answer (score 0):

here is a working code 
http://codepen.io/mozzi/pen/akwVrg

I've change the javascript to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.flashcard').on('click', function() {
$(this).toggleClass('flipped');
});
});
```